# Django ListView count all keys in a JSON variable

Tags: json, django, django-templates, django-template-filters, django-jsonfield

I would like to return in my Link.html the number of links contained in `allLinks` JSON variable.
So far I guess I misunderstand the use of `get_context_data()` and how to pass in `context['CountLink']` the total count of links for each `Post`.

With the current code, I got:

> Liste des recherches
>
> ```py
> terre : <QuerySet [<Post: terre>, <Post: océan>]> Links
> océan : <QuerySet [<Post: terre>, <Post: océan>]> Links
> ```

models.py

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    allLinks = models.JSONField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```py
class LinkView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'link.html' 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['CountLink'] = Post.objects.all()
        return context
```

Link.html

```py
  {% for post in object_list %}
  <li>
    <a href="{% url 'DetailLink' post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a> :
    {{CountLink}} Links
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
```

Example of `allLinks`: `{"0": "github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases/tag/v1.26.0", "1": "kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes",}`

Comment: Please *don't* use JSON blobs... Use a `ManyTOManyField`...

Comment: exemple of allLinks : {"0": "https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases/tag/v1.26.0", "1": "https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/",}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in [`length`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#length) template filter:

```html
{{ post.allLinks|length }} Links
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use count()
In your case I think you want something like that, it will return count of Post model objects

```
context['CountLink'] = Post.objects.all().count()
```

For more info check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/)

Comment: I am looking for counting the links inside  Post.allLinks json variable, not for all Post instance

Comment: https://dev.to/saschalalala/aggregation-in-django-jsonfields-4kg5